# How to using static method of my class java in qt6

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, qt6

i have:
MyFile.java:

```
import android.net.Uri
import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor

package org.qtproject.example.p2p; // what I need write here?
public class MyFile {
    static int getFdFromString(ContentResolver cr, String suri) {
        var uri = Uri(suri);
        var fd = cr.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        var res = fd.getFd();
        return res;
    }
}
```

and this code in my app:

```
qDebug("================================================================================================");
    auto activity = QJniObject(QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context());
    QJniObject uriString = QJniObject::fromString(filename);
    QJniObject contentResolver = activity.callObjectMethod("getContentResolver", "()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;");
    jint fd = QJniObject::callStaticMethod<jint>("MyFile",  // what I need to write without "MyFile"?
                                                       "getFdFromString",
                                                       "(Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Ljava/lang/String)I",
                                                       contentResolver.object<jobject>(), uriString.object<jobject>());
    qDebug() << fd;
    qDebug("================================================================================================");
```

How to connect this files? (run static method from Qt(c++) code)

Upd: ok... I don't say about my project struct:
p2p/main.cpp, p2p/p2p.pro, p2p/...(other files .cpp and .h of my app)

in p2p/ I don't have any folders(as android or ...).
What folders I need create and move "MyFile.java" to them?

Upd2: Qt is start point of my app.

Comment: Does this code work?

Comment: Typically if in Java you have to specify a class name this means the fully qualified class name including package name. So based on your posted Java code it should be `"org.qtproject.example.p2p.MyFile"`. I would also recommend to make the used static method `public`, not sure if this is relevant for using it from Qt but it does not hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help ?

```
 jint fd = QJniObject::callStaticMethod<jint>("org/qtproject/example/p2p",
                                                           "getFdFromString",
                                                           "(Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Ljava/lang/String)I",
                                                           contentResolver.object<jobject>(), uriString.object<jobject>());
```

I think the path to your java class is

> org/qtproject/example/p2p

Also correcet your java file , make the package the first line in your file , then come the imports

```
package org.qtproject.example.p2p;
import android.net.Uri
import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor

     
    public class MyFile {
        static int getFdFromString(ContentResolver cr, String suri) {
            var uri = Uri(suri);
            var fd = cr.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            var res = fd.getFd();
            return res;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understood how I should create files. I have p2p/main.cpp, p2p/p2p.pro, p2p/...(other files .cpp and .h of my app), where I should create java class? p2p/android/org/qtproject/example/p2p? Or in another path?